# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' in sfml

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, sfml

I wrote an sfml program to draw a rectangle grid using 2D array of sf::RectangleShape, and when you press the Up key on your keyboard, the rows and columns of the array will expand. Here is my code:

CardGrid.h

```
    class CardGrid : public sf::Drawable, sf::Transformable {
private:
    sf::RectangleShape** squares;
    sf::Color color;
    int rows = 1 , cols = 1;
public:
    CardGrid();
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& window, sf::RenderStates states) const;
    void addEvents();
  
    void setFillcolor(sf::Color color);
    void fillArray();
    sf::RectangleShape newRectangleShape(float x, float y);
    sf::RectangleShape** createArray();
```

CardGrid.cpp

```
CardGrid::CardGrid() {
    this->createArray();
    this->setFillcolor(sf::Color::White);
    this->fillArray();

}
void CardGrid::draw(sf::RenderTarget &window, sf::RenderStates states) const {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            window.draw(squares[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
void CardGrid::setFillcolor(sf::Color color) {
    this->color = color;
}
sf::RectangleShape CardGrid::newRectangleShape(float x, float y)
{
    sf::RectangleShape s;
    s.setSize({10.f,10.f});
    s.setFillColor(color);
    s.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(x+=25,y+=25));

}
void CardGrid::fillArray()
{
    float x = 10,y = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->cols; j++)
        {
            squares[i][j] = newRectangleShape(x,y);
        }
    }
}

sf::RectangleShape** CardGrid::createArray()
{
    squares = new sf::RectangleShape*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        squares[i] = new sf::RectangleShape[cols];

    }
    return squares;
}
void CardGrid::addEvents() {
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
    {
        this->cols += 1;
        this->rows += 1;
    }
    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
    {
        this->cols -= 1;
        this->rows -= 1;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "CardGrid.h"
int main() {
   

     sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500, 500, 32), "Test");
        CardGrid grid;
        while(window.isOpen())
        {
            sf::Event event;
            while(window.pollEvent(event)){
                if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
                    window.close();
                }
            }
            window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
            grid.addEvents();
            window.draw(grid);
            window.display();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

But when I tried to run the program, I encountered this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Anyone has an idea of where might the problem be and how should I fix it? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: `sf::RectangleShape CardGrid::newRectangleShape(float x, float y)` isn't returning anything. Do you not receive a warning for that? You should consider running the code in a debugger so you can see where the crash happens. What do you expect to happen when you change `rows` and `cols`? I don't see anything that would resize the array you have allocated or prevent the values from going negative.

Comment: This usually indicates that you're trying to allocate a huge amount of memory at some place in your program. Make sure that the variables used to give the memory size are positive values and always are initialized.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I set the function to return s now and the error remains the same. Isn't changing the rows and cols suppose to change the size of my array? If not so, what do you recommend for changing the size of the array using rows and columns?